# how to prevent Default event in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, preventdefault

how to prevent Default event in mobile?
eventDefault  didn't work?
please in chrome test
please in chrome test
please in chrome test
please in chrome test

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
  <style type="text/css">
    div img {
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body data-role="page">
  <p>this is test</p>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/eg_tulip.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/eg_tulip.jpg">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("div img").on("taphold", function(event) {
      console.log("11333333");
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I taphold  I don't want him to pop the default menu

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pointer-events: none;` in css:

```
div img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value.
>
> The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible.

Comment: pc chrome try fail,but mobile is ok,tanks

Comment: this method can prevent all event  but my custom event is not wrok